# Apply shadow to image only if image is loaded?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to apply box shadow property for my image only if image is rendered.If the image is not loaded box-shadow property:none should perform.Is it possible?

Comment: Hi Welcome to SO. Please read the [help]. Your question is not clear and lacks the minimal amount of information that would be required to answer it. Please add more details.

Comment: Just a friendly tip, you may want to read over this page: [The How-To-Ask Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you can always be sure that your questions are easily answerable and as clear as possible. Be sure to include any efforts you've made to fix the problem you're having, and what happened when you attempted those fixes. Also don't forget to your code and any error messages!

Answer (score 5):

You can add a class when the images are already loaded.

#### JS

```
var yourImage = document.getElementById('yourImage');
yourImage.onload = function(){
    yourImage.classList.add('boxShadow');
};
```

#### CSS

```
.boxShadow{
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with JavaScript, by waiting for onload, then setting the property

```
var image = document.getElementById("yourImage");
image.onload = function() {
    image.style.boxShadow = "10px 20px 30px blue";
}
```